# What is a '翠烟衫'?

Tags: translation, meaning

I've stumbled upon these words and I can't get the proper English translation for them.

At first I thought the 翠 here describe the color of 烟衫, but after trying to find more example, I found that they are usually accompanied by 'color' in front of them. For example:
- 碧绿的翠烟衫
- 蓝色的翠烟衫
- 黄色的翠烟衫

Answer (score 1):

> 原句子：   碧绿的翠烟衫，散花水雾绿草百褶裙，身披**翠水薄烟**纱，肩若削成腰若约素，肌若凝脂气若幽兰。娇媚无骨入艳三分。

翠 stands for 翠水 'blue green water'

烟 stands for 薄烟 'thin smoke'

翠烟衫 give people the impression of 'soft like flowing water in river and lake (water look green in lakes because it reflects the forested mountains surrounding the lake); semi transparent like thin smoke.

I would describe dress like that as "loose thin summer dress"

*Doesn't this dress look like flowing water and thin smoke?*
[image: 翠烟衫]

Answer (score 0):

It's a kind of outfit a woman wears at ancient times.
https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=%E7%BF%A0%E7%83%9F%E8%A1%AB&client=safari&rls=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2zpf-rNPVAhXKP48KHTeJAJE4ChD8BQgKKAE&biw=1440&bih=812